# Find employees latest activity is slow when adding ORDER BY

Tags: mysql

I am working on a legacy system in Laravel and I am trying to pull the latest action of some specific types of actions an `employee` has done.

Performance is good when I don't add `ORDER BY`. When adding it the query will go from something like 130 ms to 18 seconds. There are about 1.5 million rows in the `actions` table.

How do I fix the performance problem?

I have tried to isolate the problem by cutting out all the other parts of the query so it is more readable for you:

```
SELECT
    employees.id,
    (
        SELECT DATE_FORMAT(actions.date, '%Y-%m-%d')
        FROM pivot
        JOIN actions
        ON pivot.actions_id = actions.id
        WHERE employees.id = pivot.employee_id
        AND (actions.type = 'meeting'
            OR (actions.type = 'phone_call'
            AND JSON_VALID(actions.data) = 1
            AND actions.data->>'$.update_status' = 1))
        LIMIT 1
    ) AS latest_action
FROM employees
ORDER BY latest_action DESC
```

I tried using `LEFT JOIN` and `MAX()` instead but it didn't seem to solve my problem.

I just added a subquery because it was the original query is already very complex. But if you have an alternative suggestion I am all ears.

**UPDATE**

Result of `EXPLAIN`:

```
id  select_type         table       partitions  type    possible_keys                       key                 key_len ref                     rows    filtered    Extra
1   PRIMARY             employees   NULL        ALL     NULL                                NULL                NULL    NULL                    15217   10          Using where
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  pivot       NULL        ref     actions_type_index,pivot_type_index pivot_type_index    4       dev.employees.id        104     11.11       Using index condition
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  actions     NULL        eq_ref  PRIMARY,Logs                        PRIMARY             4       dev.pivot.actions_id    1       6.68        Using where
```

**UPDATE 2**

Here is the indexes. The index `employee_type` I don't think is important for my specific query, but maybe it should be re-worked?

```
# pivot table
KEY `actions_type_index` (`actions_id`,`employee_type`),
KEY `pivot_type_index` (`employee_id`,`employee_type`)

# actions table
KEY `Logs` (`type`,`id`,`is_log`)
# I tried to add `date` index to `actions` table but the problem remains.
KEY `date_index` (`date`)
```

Comment: The subquery itself is not a problem. Could you run an `EXPLAIN` on your query and add it to your question?

Comment: Please describe table structure (including indexes). Ordering on an un-indexed column could explain the observed behavior.

Comment: From what I see on the `EXPLAIN` output, your query itself is sound. However, I don't think there is any guarantee that your query is getting the latest results, since you are using `LIMIT` in your subquery but doing the ordering in the *outer* query. Also, you are ordering your query based on a *calculated* value, which might explain the poor performance. Try selecting the raw date on your subquery and then using `DATE_FORMAT` on the outer query, using order by on *both* queries, the outer one being ordered by the raw date

Comment: @Cascader I have added the indexes to my question.

Comment: @Ayrton I have tried remove `DATE_FORMAT()` and only using `ORDER BY` on the outer query. Performance is still bad. Even though I didn't even put an `ORDER BY` in the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your query is very non-optimal.
I would rewrite it this way:

```sql
SELECT
    e.id,
    DATE_FORMAT(vMAX(a.date), '%Y-%m-%d') AS latest_action
FROM employees e
LEFT JOIN pivot p ON p.employee_id = e.id
LEFT JOIN actions a ON p.actions_id = a.id AND (a.type = 'meeting'
    OR (a.type = 'phone_call'
    AND JSON_VALID(a.data) = 1
    AND a.data->>'$.update_status' = 1))
GROUP BY e.id
ORDER BY latest_action DESC
```

Obviously there must be indexes on `p.employee_id`, `p.actions_id`, `a.date`. Also would be good on `a.type`.
Also it would be good to replace `a.data->>'$.update_status'` with some simple field with an index on it.

Comment: Following your advice about indexes  and removing `a.data` condition still give me the same problem. Removing `ORDER BY` helps a little bit.